# difference between more than and rather than

Tags: meaning

> I like more apples than oranges.
>
> I like apples rather than oranges.

Could anyone tell me the shades of meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Well one difference is that

> 1. I like more apples than oranges.

is wrong but

> 2. I like apples, rather than oranges.

is correct.

For 1 you may have been thinking of

> 3. I like apples more than oranges.

Which is correct.

2 and 3 are nearly the same.  The subtle difference is that 3 implies that you like oranges, just not as much as you like apples.  2 doesn't indicate like oranges at all.

Note: when I say 1 is wrong it's only because I'm assuming you don't mean of all the apples and oranges you've tried you've liked more of the apples.  This would mean you're judging each on a case by case basis.  If you had 3 apples and 2 oranges and liked them all then technically you liked more apples than oranges.  But that's a bit silly.

Comment: Another meaning for #1 could be about proportion e.g. *"When you're making juice, do you like to use equal quantities of apples and oranges?"*. Agree it's probably not what the OP was looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions are not very good English. Better options include:

> I prefer apples to oranges.
>
> I like apples more than oranges.

"Rather than" doesn't really fit well here at all. You could use it like this, though:

> Rather than oranges, she chose to eat apples …

… but even that is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: 'Here' needs to be better defined. 'I like apples rather than oranges.' may be used as a corrective in a formal register: 'All the children in my class this year brought me oranges at Christmas, because my previous class had told them I like fruit. I wish they'd added that I like apples rather than oranges.'